# When to assign functions to variable, using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

so I've been messing around with some Jquery Ajax promises/deffers etc... and i've come across something I don't completely understand, not strictly related to the Jquery Ajax.

I have always declared and called functions like so:

```
function foo1() { //sets function
    alert('foo1');
}

foo1(); //calls function
```

But it seems the more I see different code a lot of people are declaring functions like the following, I just copied and pasted an example I saw so I would't miss anything:

```
var promise = $.ajax({
    url: "/myServerScript"
});

promise.done(myStopAnimationFunction);
```

I understand what the above does, just an example.

The question is, is it better to assign functions to variables? What are the pros/cons, and in what situations is this way used?
At what point in this code is the actual function called. Does

```
    promise.done(myStopAnimationFunction);
```

call both the ajax function, and then the callback, or just the callback?

Thanks

Comment: _"Does `promise.done(myStopAnimationFunction);` call both the ajax function, and then the callback, or just the callback?"_ - Actually it's option (c) That line calls just the `.done()` method to tell jQuery that you want it to call your `myStopAnimationFunction` at a later point after the Ajax request is done. It is jQuery that eventually calls your callback.

Comment: The promise object has some properties that are functions (or function pointers if javascript had pointers) and you can call them. Its handy and jQuery's `$.ajax()` uses that to provide functions you can call to let you control the ajax process and be notified of how its going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you're assigning your `promise` variable to what `$.ajax` returns (which is a [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object)

```
var promise = $.ajax({
    url: "/myServerScript"
});
```

Your then saying that once it's done, you want to call `myStopAnimationFunction`. Because `$.ajax` is `async` by default, the browser will skip right over this and only call your `myStopAnimationFunction` when the request is complete.

```
promise.done(myStopAnimationFunction);
```

Now, with your `myStopAnimationFunction`; you could always just do the following:

```
promise.done(function(){
    $('.loader').hide();
});
```

but if you have code which you'll be using a lot, put it in a function so you don't need to repeat yourself (see [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) - this has nothing to do with jQuery, however.

Your example is exactly the same as doing:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/myServerScript"
}).done(function(){
    $('.loader').hide();
});
```

Comment: so: var promise = $.ajax({
    url: "/myServerScript"
}); starts/runs that function

Comment: @JamesGP, it sure does

Answer (score 2):

Those are two very different things! The first one is a function declaration. The second one is a function invocation, and what is assigned to the `promise` variable is the value returned by the function you're calling (`$.ajax)`.

In any case, it is possible to assign functions to variables too (but I'm not sure if that's what you're really asking – if it is, this is a duplicate of [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)).

---

> Does `promise.done(myStopAnimationFunction);`
>   call both the ajax function, and then the callback, or just the callback?

Neither. That line is a call to `done` on the `promise` object, to *register* a callback to be called when the ajax response arrives. At that point you call `done`, the ajax request may have already fired, and the response even might already be available (if that's the case, the callback will be called immediately).

Comment: I'm glad it did! I hope you clarified your doubts.